# How does this video file crash discord?

Tags: discord, code-injection, video-encoding, webm

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/882079986599751680/954144030449631332/UOOOOPA.webm
```

**this video will crash your discord if you open it in discord (do it at your own risk)**

i was wondering how this video achieves that. i downloaded and hexdumped the video and found that at the end of it, a series of data is repeated which might be the cause of this thing actually crashing discord. (it crashes discord when it reaches the end)
you can see the pattern in the image.
[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ngo.png)

this goes down from offset `00036680` to `000375e0`.

```
HEX   : 40 b4 d3  4d 34 d3 4c 8c 00  00  00  08 40
ASCII : @         M  4     L     NUL NUL NUL BS  @
```

this looks to  be the pattern that is getting repeated.

i also found another set of repeating data going from offset `00033c90` to `000364a0` which is exactly behind the one above. [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Pyv.png)

```
52 a9 52 a5 52 a5 4a a5 4a 95 4a 95 2a 95 2a 
55 2a 54 aa 54 a9 54 a9 52 a9 52 a5 52 a5 4a 
a5 4a 95  4a 95 2a 95 2a 55 2a 54  aa 54 a9 54
```

this looks to be the data that is repeating.

i dont know if its a common thing in webm videos or its a malicious data injected into it.

how are these kind of videos made?
(i've also seen some other webm videos that have infinite time)

Comment: it works because someone made a mistake and failed to account for this case while trying to make video decoding as performant as they needed.